# Nothing is working. Realm Migration [Android 1.2]

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I updated to the latest version hoping it would fix my issue, but it has not. I am using

```
  RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .name("myrealm.realm")
           .migration(new Migration())
            .schemaVersion(2) // 2
            .build();
    try {
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config); // Automatically run migration if needed
        realm.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

This code to update and add a few new objects. Here is my migration

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
@Override
public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    // Access the Realm schema in order to create, modify or delete classes and their fields.
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
    // Migrate from version 1 to version 2
    if (oldVersion == 1) {
        // Create a new classes
        RealmObjectSchema styleSchema = schema.create("SavedStyle").addField("title", String.class).addField("json", String.class);
        RealmObjectSchema dictSchema = schema.create("SavedDictionary").addField("title", String.class).addField("dictionary", String.class);
        RealmObjectSchema journalSchema = schema.create("CustomJournal").addField("title", String.class).addField("json", String.class);
        oldVersion++;
    }
    if (oldVersion < newVersion) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Migration missing from v%d to v%d", oldVersion, newVersion));
    }
}
```

}

I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file. The most likely cause is that equals() and hashCode() are not overridden in the migration class: otherClasses.Migration
```

When just trying to run it standalone without updating from a previous version even. Not really sure what to do anymore. Really need it to work so I don't have to wipe everyone's data though. Thinking about making a more formal bug report, but wanted to check if anyone else knows if there is a solution first. The issue occurs whenever I try to get a default configuration. It usually works when I first open the app, but then crashes when I go to the next activity

Comment: I like how you've probably seen this yet you never bothered to reply. I guess the question wasn't **that** important.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the error message is quite specific, and it says you should do the following

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(final DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
         return object != null && object instanceof Migration;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
         return Migration.class.hashCode();
    }
}
```